# How can I consume data from specific partitions in Kafka using Confluent Python?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I tried this code but it is consuming from other partitions as well but my req is to consume from 1 and 2 partition

```
          ConsumerKafka.subscribe(topic_list)
          ConsumerKafka.assign([TopicPartition(topic_name, 1, 2)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove subscribe call to consume from only specific partitions

Also, you need two element list

`[TopicPartition(topic_name, p) for p in [1,2]]`